# Font size and weight in Application Bar in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to duplicate a popup menu shown from a Application bar button (like Reply in the standard Mail app) and I need to know the font size and font weight of the Application bar menu items.

I did som trial and error but I cannot match the size and weight exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font size: PhoneFontSizeLarge
Font family: PhoneFontFamilySemiLight

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a ContextMenu?

Using the following XAML :-

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True"
                                 x:Name="ContextMenu">
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item1"
                                  Header="Item 1"/>
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item2"
                                  Header="Item 2" />
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item3"
                                  Header="Item 3" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
```

And the following Application Bar XAML :-

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True"
                          IsMenuEnabled="True"
                          x:Name="MyAppBar">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png"
                                        Text="Button 1" 
                                        Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

And the following XMLNS (You need to add the Windows Phone Toolkit via Nuget):-

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

And then finally the following C# :-

```
    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
        ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;          
    }
```

The ContextMenu pops up in a similar way to the Email reply pop up menu.

Comment: my question is not about creating the popup, it is about styling it so it looks exactly like the menu items in application bar

Comment: I believe using the pop up in the way I described meets this goal. Have you tried my possible solution to see if it meets your needs?

Comment: Yes I did and the styles do not match

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
FontSize="33"
FontWeight="Light"
```

Comment: Looks like PhoneFontSizeLarge and PhoneFontFamilySemiLight may be the match